# Active Directory Search Filter Failing when Searching different Server

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

Good morning,

I am working on a graphical application which searches active directory for information about users and returns certain fields. My company has two servers for active directory, which we will call Server A and Server B. When I attempt to search for users by last name, it works perfectly for Server A (which is the default server), but I get an error that the filter was invalid when attempting to search Server B. I've tried storing the search string in a variable and writing it out fully, but I'm not finding any other questions on google or stack exchange dealing with a similar problem. Note that I can search by user ID on Server B; the search function is only failing when attempting to search by surname. My search function follows:

```
function Search{
    $uidr = [regex]'[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}'
    $script:op = ''
    $script:list = $null
    [array]$y = $null
    #$uidr is a regex string to match user ids
    if($script:x -match $uidr){
        try{
            $y = Get-ADUser $script:x -Properties cC
            #using select instead of $y.property for compatibility
            $ad = ($y | select -ExpandProperty samAccountName) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty Name) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty cC)
            $script:op = $ad
        }
        catch{
            try{
                $y = Get-ADUser $script:x -Server B.Server.com -Properties Title
                $ad = ($y | select -ExpandProperty samAccountName) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty Name) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty Title)
                $script:op = $ad
            }
            catch{
                $script:op = 'User ID Not Found'
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $script:list = $null
        try{
            $y = Get-ADUser -Filter "surname -eq '$script:x'" -Properties cC
        }
        catch{
            try{
                $y = Get-ADUser -Server B.Server.com -Filter "surname -eq '$script:x'" -Properties Title
            }
            catch{
                $script:op = 'No user with that last name found. Check spelling and try again.'
            }
        }
        #This if/else is always defaulting to last when last name stored on server B but not server A is entered. $y.count must be 0
        if($y.Count -gt 1){
            foreach($u in $y){
                [array]$script:list += $u.name
            }
            foreach($l in ($script:list | select -Unique)){
                $listbox += $l
            }
        }
        elseif($y.Count -eq 1){
            $m = $y | select -ExpandProperty cC
            if($m -ne $null){
                $ad = ($y | select -ExpandProperty samAccountName) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty Name) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty cC)
                $script:op = $ad.tostring()
            }
            else{
                $ad = ($y | select -ExpandProperty samAccountName) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty Name) + ' | ' + ($y | select -ExpandProperty Title)
                $script:op = $ad.tostring()
            }
        }
        elseif($y.count -eq 0){
            $script:op = 'No user with that last name found. Check spelling and try again.'
        }
    }
    if($script:op -eq ''){
        continue
    }
    else{
        write-host $script:op
    }
}
```

Currently every aspect of this is working except the last name search for Server B. The function itself is just returning 'no user with that last name found', but I was able to isolate it to the filter when attempting to search for last names.

Note that I also attempted just running the search function as a standalone script with a last name I know is on server B written directly into the filter, and still got back 'no user with this last name found'

I do not see what is wrong with the filter though. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hm, your filter syntax looks a little off to me, I'd try doing it this way: `-Filter {surname -eq $script:x}` Just seeing your error makes me think that it's searching for a literal '$script:x' or something akin to that.

Comment: @JacobColvin, just tried. That did not work. I did previously have an error with it searching for a literal $script in other parts of the function, and at the time I had it formatted with curly brackets rather than quotes, and that was fixed by making the switch to quotes.

Comment: You're right. I just tried with your exact syntax (I queried my surname via copy&pasting your code and setting $x to my surname), and it worked for me. Maybe something wrong with your user account attributes? I am not certain.

Comment: @JacobColvin, it is working perfectly for me when I try a standalone ad query, the only time it's not working is when passed through the search function. I think maybe the $x variable is being cleared somewhere, but I don't see where that would happen

Comment: I recommend creating an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) instead and updating your question.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I have removed all gui manipulation remaining in the function. I cannot make it more SSCCE compliant without having active directory servers already included.

Comment: Start more slowly. Run individual commands and verify whether they work. If so, you can slowly start to incorporate the other code, a little bit at a time. In so doing, you will probably discover your mistake(s).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I had attempted that, and every individual command I was running was working. I have actually just fixed this issue by replacing the try/catch statement where I was attempting to search Server B with an if statement that checks if $y -eq $null. I'm not sure why this works and not try/catch, but it does.

Comment: @Cameron `Get-ADUser` doesn't give a terminating error without `-ErrorAction Stop` which is why it didn't `catch`

Comment: @BenH, thank you, that explains a lot. That knowledge will be very helpful in my future endeavours.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was with the fact that I was using Try/Catch. I fixed the issue by replacing the Try/Catch with an If Statement:

```
else{
    $script:list = $null
    $y = Get-ADUser -Filter "surname -eq '$script:x'" -Properties cC
    if($y -eq $null){
        $y = Get-ADUser -Server B.Server.com -Filter "surname -eq '$script:x'" -Properties Title
    }
    if($y -eq $null){
        $script:op = 'No user with that last name found. Check spelling and try again.'
    }
}
```